# How to set up PulseAudio remote properly and securely?

Tags: networking, audio, pulseaudio, remote

I saw a forum post about someone who was using PulseAudio remote (client-server setup) and this interested me. PulseAudio has some very advanced features that I hope to use to be able to play music throughout my house without buying a commercial system such as Sonos to do that.

So far I was able to get PulseAudio remote working, but not exactly according to the [directions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples#PulseAudio_over_network) given. In particular, I think I have opened up some security holes. I would like to give the exact steps I performed and see if anyone can tell me where I went wrong.

To be clear, PulseAudio is working and I do not get errors. But I had to open up more settings than I should have. My goal is to go from this poor working configuration to a proper and secure working configuration.

My PulseAudio client and server both run Arch Linux.

## client and server both

Install this package and enable avahi-daemon:

```
pacman -S pulseaudio-zeroconf 
systemctl enable avahi-daemon.service
systemctl start avahi-daemon.service
```

## server steps

Edit `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and add these lines:

```
load-module module-native-protocol-tcp auth-ip-acl=127.0.0.1;192.168.0.0/24 auth-anonymous=1
load-module module-zeroconf-publish
```

Run these commands:

```
pulseaudio -k
pulseaudio --start
pacmd list-modules | grep native-protocol-tcp
pacmd list-modules | grep zeroconf-publish
```

The modules were correct.

## client steps

Edit `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and add these lines:

```
load-module module-native-protocol-tcp
load-module module-zeroconf-discover
```

Run these commands:

```
pulseaudio -k
pulseaudio --start
pacmd list-modules | grep native-protocol-tcp
pacmd list-modules | grep zeroconf-discover
```

PulseAudio started and the modules were correct.

My next step should have been, "Run the graphical PulseAudio Volume Control `pavucontrol`. Under the Output Devices tab, you should see the local and remote output devices." However, when doing that, I did not see any remote output devices on the client.

I had to open `paprefs` in a terminal and do the following extra steps:

Network Access tab on client:

- check Make discoverable PulseAudio network sound devices available locally

Network Server tab on server:

- check Enable network access to local sound devices
- check Allow other machines on the LAN to discover local sound devices
- check Don't require authentication

Only after those changes in the GUI of `paprefs` did I see remote output devices on the client. As mentioned, playing music to a remote sink is working, but these settings seem insecure and I suspect I missed something important in my configuration. As soon as I uncheck "Don't require authentication", streaming stops.

Also, is there a better way to do this than using avahi?

Comment: What is the package name on Ubuntu?

Comment: @AaronFranke see https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-updates-universe-amd64/pulseaudio-module-zeroconf_13.99.1-1ubuntu3.3_amd64.deb.html

Comment: I have `pulseaudio-module-zeroconf` installed, but the checkboxes in `paprefs` are still grayed out. Any ideas?

Comment: @AaronFranke I don't use Ubuntu, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the server, I changed the following config line from:

```
load-module module-native-protocol-tcp auth-ip-acl=127.0.0.1;192.168.0.0/24 auth-anonymous=1
```

to:

```
load-module module-native-protocol-tcp auth-ip-acl=127.0.0.1;192.168.0.0/24
```

I copied the same ~/.config/pulse/cookie file to all devices.

Next, on the server open paprefs in a terminal and do the following step:

Activate Network Server tab:

- uncheck "Don't require authentication"

## cmus

I also found another way to accomplish basically the same thing, which is controlling music playback from my laptop while the music is played on/through a different computer which acts as a music "server" and is connected to the speakers (and DAC, power amplifier or whatever music setup one has). I have convenient ssh access set up between the devices on my LAN. I installed the application [**cmus**](https://cmus.github.io/) on my music server.

> cmus is a small, fast and powerful console music player for Unix-like operating systems.

Now I can use my laptop (or phone) as a "remote control" for my music server by ssh'ing into the music server and typing `cmus` into a terminal. I have tried other methods of remote controlling music being played on a different computer, and I have to say there is an enticing elegance in the console interface of cmus.

For cmus instructions, type `man cmus-tutorial` and `man cmus`.

Comment: sorry, just a basic question for you: is pulseaudio streaming working well for you? especially in terms of lags, buffering and sound quality.. I have been using it years ago and it was awaful (lags) so I wonder how things changed over the time.

Comment: Yes, it is working well enough for me now. On my LAN I had to set latency_msec=2000, and I use unicasting (to multiple receivers) instead of multicasting.