# PulseAudio as remote source *and* sink?

Tags: pulseaudio, remote, remote-control

I'm an amateur radio operator, and I use a software package called WSJT-X to connect my computer to my radio to operate it using what we call "digital modes". This works by sending audio signals from the speaker output of a USB sound card to my radio, and reading audio signals from the microphone input on that same card. Because I am lazy, and my nice TV with the nice speakers and comfy couch is upstairs, but my computer and radio are downstairs, I'd like to run WSTJ-X from my laptop upstairs. I know that it's possible to use PulseAudio as a remote audio *sink*, but is it possible to use it as a remote *source* as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, [you can](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Network/#index3h3) (this is an example of something you can do):

> **How can I use PulseAudio to share a single LINE-IN/MIC jack on the
> entire LAN?**
>
> On the sender side simply load the RTP sender module:
>
> load-module module-rtp-send
>
> On the reciever sides, create an RTP source:
>
> load-module module-null-sink sink_name=rtp load-module module-rtp-recv
> sink=rtp set-default-source rtp_monitor
>
> Now the audio data will be available from the default source
> rtp_monitor.

[This](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples) can help you with the setup. You will have to add both the input sink and the output one.

You might also want to read [How to set up PulseAudio remote properly and securely?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/470961/how-to-set-up-pulseaudio-remote-properly-and-securely).